# Getting No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' when sending large JSON via AJAX

Tags: ajax, json, web-services, base64

I'm working on a web page that calls a REST webservice via ajax to get and insert data.

**The problem is that we need to send a base64 image in a JSON.** You know, the base64 image is the imaged converted to that large text: base64/fjhd7879djkdadys7d9adsdkjasjdshk...

When we try with a 1 KB image, it works. 
[image]

But with a bigger file(55kb), it doesn't.
[image]

So I assume it has something to do with the maxRequest, but the error says that is No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. But we havent fount any way to configure it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

By default browsers block json requests from other domains other than the page unless the json request has the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so you'll need to add that header to your json requests on that service or use the same domain for both.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: But with a short base64 string it works. Without adding any header

Comment: You must have a hardcoded url other than localhost, check that out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the maxJsonLength to it's maximum value in the web.config file.

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but for anyone who still might be having this problem, I solved it by adding two settings to Web.config as described here: https://west-wind.com/webconnection/docs/_4lp0zgm9d.htm

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647"></requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!--snip-->

</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />

    <!--snip-->

</system.web>
```